# Python - merging netcdf files having time duplicates

Tags: python, file, merge, netcdf, python-xarray

I have several netCDF files from MODIS satellite data. I would like to merge those files. For that I am using the followings commands (in python):

```
data = data_1.merge(data_2)
```

or I just open the files using the following:

```
data = xr.open_mfdataset('MCD43A3*.nc')
```

My problem is that the end of 1 file is a the duplicate of the beginning of the next file. so I end up with files having duplicates:

```
lat;lon;time;var1;var2
10;10;2000-01-01;22;55
      2000-01-02;12;87
      2000-01-03;57;65
      2000-01-04;45;67
      2000-01-04;45;67
      2000-01-05;78;15
```

How can I either remove the last timestamp of the time series or merge without having duplicates?

note: the input files have a julian calendar therefore and unfortunately CDO/NCO commands does not work

Comment: Couldn't you merge them anyway and then run `uniq` on them? (If you have access to Unix utilities :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to use `nco`. e.g. if you have 4 timestamps and want to remove the last one,

```
ncks -d time,0,2 in.nc out.nc
```

or remove the first one:

```
ncks -d time,1,3 in.nc out.nc
```

Answer (score 2):

Were you using the CDO command "seldate" to make the selection?

You might still be able to do it using seltimestep:

```
cdo seltimestep,first/last in.nc out.nc
```

Another option might be to try and convert the calendar first using

```
cdo setcalendar,standard in.nc out.nc
```

and then using seldate...